# How to get multiple accounts info with jsonParsed encoding using @solana/web3.js?

Tags: token, javascript, balance, web3.js

Currently, I can do this using a cURL request:

```
 curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getMultipleAccounts",
    "params": [
      [
        "AWaJ4oXHWXaNnFJirydYdXdD3Yjmkgh6rYhmwAyB5d8o",
        "yT2bBMrE4AVG3BM8LHjDSr1yketzabmfp3rYimS36C9"
      ],
      {
        "encoding": "jsonParsed"
      }
    ]
  }
'
```

This will return a response that contains JSON parsed data that is human readable:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "context": {
      "apiVersion": "1.10.29",
      "slot": 150852465
    },
    "value": [
      {
        "data": {
          "parsed": {
            "info": {
              "isNative": false,
              "mint": "4koajw4GkCgVNEjN14xmjCtMVYNASdDj7RtrAA4SZwnK",
              "owner": "GkeDRfHcACap2CM9oaWrb3QUMG7pk6F6EMYca8Lu52t8",
              "state": "initialized",
              "tokenAmount": {
                "amount": "12998020",
                "decimals": 6,
                "uiAmount": 12.99802,
                "uiAmountString": "12.99802"
              }
            },
            "type": "account"
          },
          "program": "spl-token",
          "space": 165
        },
        "executable": false,
        "lamports": 2039280,
        "owner": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
        "rentEpoch": 348
      }
    ]
  },
  "id": 1
}
```

I want to use the same method by using the @solana/web3.js library:

```
const accounts = await connection.getMultipleAccountsInfo([new PublicKey("AWaJ4oXHWXaNnFJirydYdXdD3Yjmkgh6rYhmwAyB5d8o"), new PublicKey("yT2bBMrE4AVG3BM8LHjDSr1yketzabmfp3rYimS36C9")]);
```

This doesn't return JSON parsed account data, but it's using `Buffer`. I can use the method `connection.getParsedAccountInfo()` to get the JSON parsed data and it works great, but it's not efficient. I will be parsing multiple token balances from 500+ accounts. Is it possible to convert the Buffer structure to parse token balance from it? I would need the uiAmountString:

[image]

Everything works perfectly fine by using a cURL request, but the web3.js library doesn't seem to have this implemented?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like the web3.js [implementation](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getMultipleAccountsInfo)  of `getMultipleAccounts` supports parsed encoding replies.  You can either open a feature request issue against the library in the [monorepo on github](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana) (assuming one doesn't already exist) or better yet, implement it yourself and submit a PR.

This could be implemented either by adding a new `encoding` field to the `GetMultipleAccountsConfig` structure or by adding a new method akin to `getParsedAccountInfo` (as `getParsedMultipleAccountsInfo` ?)

Answer (score 1):

For token accounts specifically, if all the token accounts you want to fetch are owned by the same pubkey, you can use [getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner).

Otherwise, I believe web3.js is just a thin wrapper around the JSON RPC API so in the worst case you can probably implement the same thing that you did in CURL in js.

Comment: Yeah, for now I've just used a good old web request for this, it's unfortunate that it's not supported yet.